# VBA Outlook Redirect Emails to Distribution List

Tags: vba, email, redirect, outlook

I have the following problem and would be extremely grateful for help:

I have a rule set up on Outlook to redirect all emails coming in from a specific email address.

However, I cannot set it to redirect the email to all the people in my distribution list named "Lecturers". In addition, I want the redirection to be BCC (due to spam issues).

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sounds like an outlook configuration issue, not a programming question? If it is about programming, please add a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a VBA macro to the existing rule as a possible action. The VBA method should look in the following way:

```
Public Sub Test(item as MailItem)
  ' your actions here
End Sub
```

So, in the VBA macro called by the Outlook rule you can implement all the required functionality. Use the [MailItem.Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients) property which returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item to set up recipients of your redirect email. Use the `Add` method to create a new `Recipient` object and add it to the `Recipients` object. The `Type` property of a new `Recipient` object is set to the default for the associated `MailItem` object and must be reset to indicate another recipient type. For example:

```
Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add ("Eugene Astafiev") 
myRecipient.Type = olBCC
```

Comment: Thank you! I understood that part. However, I found that for the redirection itself, you don't get very far with the rules. Also the combination of the rule with the script only works when outlook is open. But I would like to achieve the redirections also when outlook is not open.

So I would have to create a standalone VBA macro for the following steps:
1. trigger = an email comes in from a specific sender (e.g. law@law.com) with a specific subject (e.g. lecture).
2. this email is redirected to all recipients in the distribution list named "Lecturer" (about 200 email addresses).

Comment: Since I am not very familiar with this matter, I would be extremely grateful if you have a VBA macro for me that I can copy and paste completely.

Thank you very much!